# have problem when using two Listview builder wrap it in column scroll horizontally but they cant why?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            height: 50,
                            color: Color(0xff0B28BE),
                            child: ListView.builder(
                              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                itemCount: 1,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      SizedBox(
                                        width: 15,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        "Pmnt. \nNo.".toUpperCase(),
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        width: 15,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        "Payment. \nDate.".toUpperCase(),
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        width: 15,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        "Beginning. \nBalance.".toUpperCase(),
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        width: 15,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        "Scheduled. \nPayment.".toUpperCase(),
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        width: 15,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        "Total. \nPayment.".toUpperCase(),
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        width: 15,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        "Principle".toUpperCase(),
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        width: 15,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        "Interest".toUpperCase(),
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        width: 15,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        "Ending \nBalance".toUpperCase(),
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        width: 15,
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  );
                                })),
                        Container(
                          child: SingleChildScrollView(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                  height: 100,
                                  child: ListView.builder(
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                      itemBuilder: (context,index){
                                    return SingleChildScrollView(
                                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                      child: Column(
                                        children: [
                                          SizedBox(height: 10,),
                                          Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                            children: [
                                              SizedBox(
                                                width: 15,
                                              ),
                                              Text(
                                                "1".toUpperCase(),
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: 10, color: Colors.black),
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                              ),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                width: 15,
                                              ),
                                              Text(
                                                "20/09/2021".toUpperCase(),
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: 10, color: Colors.black),
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                              ),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                width: 15,
                                              ),
                                              Text(
                                                "1000000.00".toUpperCase(),
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: 10, color: Colors.black),
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                              ),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                width: 15,
                                              ),
                                              Text(
                                                "20/04/2022".toUpperCase(),
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: 10, color: Colors.black),
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                              ),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                width: 15,
                                              ),
                                              Text(
                                                "1200000.00".toUpperCase(),
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: 10, color: Colors.black),
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                              ),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                width: 30,
                                              ),
                                              Text(
                                                "4000.00".toUpperCase(),
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: 10, color: Colors.black),
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                              ),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                width: 40,
                                              ),
                                              Text(
                                                "5".toUpperCase(),
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: 10, color: Colors.black),
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                              ),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                width: 35,
                                              ),
                                              Text(
                                                "1600000.00".toUpperCase(),
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: 10, color: Colors.black),
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                              ),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                width: 15,
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  }),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        )

                        // Container(
                        //   child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        //     scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        //     child: Column(
                        //       children: [
                        //         SizedBox(height: 10,),
                        //
                        //       ],
                        //     ),
                        //   ),
                        // )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
```

Comment: You need to pretty-print that dumpout and mark it up as code if you want to have any hope that anyone will take a look. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help - maybe they have "your language" already under syntax highlighting or something similar to make it to do pretty-printing for you - worth a try

Answer (score 0):

you should wrap your listview.builders with Expanded widget

Here is sample code snippet :

```
    Column(
            children: [ 
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: AppBar().preferredSize.height +
                          MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top +
                          24,
                      bottom: 62 + MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom,
                    ),
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    itemCount: list.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {                                    
                        return ListItem(item: list[index]);                               
                    }),
              ),
               Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: AppBar().preferredSize.height +
                          MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top +
                          24,
                      bottom: 62 + MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom,
                    ),
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    itemCount: list.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {                                    
                        return ListItem(item: list[index]);                               
                    }),
              ),
            ],
          );
```